# Python library for Intelligent Data generation

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a system which is configurable. It has 3 parameters

- Parameter1 - can vary between `[0, 2^30]`
- Parameter2 - can vary between `[0, 2^30]`
- Parameter3 - can vary between `[0, 2^12]`

I have a python code which when given a set of valid numbers corresponding to (parameter1, parameter2, parameter3) can configure the system and after few mins return a number say a score for the configuration.

Suppose the aim to maximize the score. Is there a python library to generate the parameters with constraints intelligently.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at `scipy.optimize`. There you find a number of methods for constrained optimization: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#constrained-minimization-of-multivariate-scalar-functions-minimize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bounded optimization problem. Depending on how the "system" is structured different optimization strategies will behave differently well.

My suggestions is to either look at [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) or a genetic algorithm. I know there are multiple GA implementations in Python, but I haven't tried them.

Since a single evaluation takes on the order of minutes, you are looking at long optimization times though.
If you can compute the gradient to your score function, and if it is well-behaved (i.e. convex) then the `scipy.optimize.minimize` is probably your best bet. Otherwise you might have better luck with a GA.